# Are there any working Lua plugins for Eclipse Galileo?

Tags: eclipse, lua, galileo

I do a lot of work in Lua and work primarily in Eclipse Galileo. Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a working plugin for syntax highlighting.  I've tried pretty much all available versions of LuaEclipse and LunarEclipse (including beta previews) but has gotten me nowhere.  In both cases I get errors while installing them, referring to missing packages.

The frustrating thing is all I really care about is syntax highlighting, which should be trivial.  Has anyone else had any luck with this?

Edit:
Thanks for the suggestions. I've pasted the error I'm getting when installing LuaEclipse 1.3.1 preview below.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
  session context was:(profile=epp.package.cpp, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cvs,1.0.300.v200909170800
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.core,3.5.1.v_972_R35x
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jdt.ui,3.5.1.r351_v20090821-0800
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui,3.3.201.R35x_v20090826-0905
  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ui.views.log,1.0.100.v20090731
  No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.cvs,1.1.101.R35x_v20090811-7E79FEd9KKF5H2YDWFLLBL01A16
  No repository found containing: binary,org.eclipse.cvs_root,1.1.101.R35x_v20090811-7E79FEd9KKF5H2YDWFLLBL01A16
```

Comment: Have you installed LuaEclipse as documented? http://luaeclipse.luaforge.net/manual.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[LuaEclipse](http://luaeclipse.luaforge.net/) is the only Lua plugin for Eclipse that I can find. However there are a number of other editors you could try if it is not installing correctly for you.

[Pipmak Wiki](http://pipmak.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Lua_Editors) lists various Lua editors that you could try.

Update: Your installation error message is complaining about the absence of CVS. This error sometimes occurs when you're behind a proxy server, you can set Eclipse to use your proxy as follows:

1. Go to Window->Preferences

   - Click Install/Update
   - Check **Enable HTTP proxy connection**
   - Enter your proxy host in **HTTP proxy host address** and proxy port in **HTTP proxy host port**
   - Click OK

If you aren't behind a proxy. It may be that your P2 repository is in an inconsistent state. HAve you tried installing to a clean Eclipse install?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [EclipseColorer](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/eclipsecolorer/)? It can highlight a lot of syntaxes. In fact, if it even can't, [here](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/) you can find a documentation on how to create a new highlighting profile for particular language.

Comment: I tried this but actually get the exact same error as mentioned in the question  :(

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is not really an answer to your question, but I have a semi-working version of LuaEclipse from (https://github.com/KINFOO/LuaEclipse) which I force-compiled on Helios stubbing out things that were not compiling. The resulting plugin doesn't do much, but does syntax highlighting and catches syntax errors.  Since all you seem to care about is syntax highlighting, would you be interested in trying it out? I have a private build that I can give you to try out. Note that I've only tried it on Macbook pro and only on Eclipse Helios (not Galileo) and it's not very functional in any other way (no debugging etc).

Comment: I wouldn't mind getting a copy if you still have it. Might be willing to see if I can hook up any of the stubs as well.

Comment: The work originally being done in https://github.com/KINFOO/LuaEclipse has graduated into an official Eclipse project, you should definitely have a look! http://eclipse.org/koneki/ldt. Also, it is a one-click install since there is an update site! :)